# Why the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra is an associative algebra with a unit?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, universal-property, associativity

I have seen the definition of the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra is an associative algebra with a unit which satisfies a universal property (always exists and is unique up to isomorphism). I know it should be an associative algebra as it is a left adjoint to the commtator bracket.  However, why usually we require it has a unit? Could we define the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra to be an associative algebra without unit?

Comment: Sure, you could define it without a unit.  But why wouldn't you want to have a unit?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey I am considering a question of the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra, but I find the corresponding theory is for associative algebras without unit. Also I do not understand why we usually require it has a unit, so I asked this question.

Comment: In another universe, they could have made a non-unital enveloping algebra, and then someone could ask why they didn't make it unital. But wouldn't that be the weirder universe, since unital algebras are nicer than non-unital ones (all else equal) so it makes more sense to define a unital enveloping algebra?

Comment: There is in fact a very useful form of the universal enveloping algebra for a semisimple Lie algebra, called _Lusztig's idempotent form_, which is not unital. However, this version needs more structure to define: a choice of Cartan and an integral weight lattice inside that Cartan.